# Logs not getting generated for Web Service published on Websphere Application Server 8

Tags: java, web-services, logging, log4j

I am new to web services and have published a web service on my localhost (Websphere Application Server 8).

I am able to consume the web service successfully but not able to find where the logs are getting generated or even the logs are getting generated or not.

I had place **log4j.properties** file in **WebContent/WEB-INF/classes**, but this file is file is automatically getting deleted when I am trying to generate WSDL from Java *(Steps - Right click on project name --> New --> Web Service --> Select Class)*.

Files that were generated:

1. deploy.wsdd
2. deploy.wsdd.bak
3. undeploy.wsdd

and some JARs getting added in **WebContent/WEB-INF/lib**.

After the file was deleted I have copied **log4j.properties** again to **WebContent/WEB-INF/classes** and exported the EAR which was deployed on server.

I have already checked logs in folders:

- D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\cw_profile\logs
- D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\logs\manageprofiles\cw_profile

but no log file was generated.

**Main web service -->**

```
package com.gateway.request.demo;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@WebService
public class GetDemoTicketv2 {

//Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GetDemoTicket.class);
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(GetDemoTicketv2.class);

public GetDemoTicketv2() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@WebMethod
public String getTicket(String serviceName, String actionName, String bodyStr, String userId){

    Date curDate = new Date();

    log.debug("Starting Execution");
    log.info("Service Name is: "+serviceName);
    log.info("Action is: "+actionName);
    log.info("Body: "+bodyStr);
    log.info("User ID is: "+userId);
    log.debug("Execution Done");
    serviceName = "Service name received: "+serviceName+" "+curDate.toString()+"\n";
    actionName = "Action name received: "+actionName+" "+curDate.toString()+"\n";
    bodyStr = "Body string received: "+bodyStr+" "+curDate.toString()+"\n";
    userId = "User ID received: "+userId+" "+curDate.toString()+"\n";
    log.info("Return Values is \n"+serviceName+actionName+bodyStr+userId);
    return serviceName+actionName+bodyStr+userId;
}

/*public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("CHECKING...");
    GetDemoTicketv2 obj = new GetDemoTicketv2();
    String retVal = obj.getTicket("My Service T", "My Action T", "My Body String T", "My User ID T");
    System.out.println(retVal);
}*/}
```

**Client -->**

```
package com.gateway.request.demo;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class TestService {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    GetDemoTicketv2Proxy pxy = new GetDemoTicketv2Proxy("http://hostname:9081/Gateway_Webservice_For_ISTM_v3.0/GetDemoTicketv2Service");
    try {
        String retVal = pxy.getTicket("SERVICE", "ACTION", "BODY", "USER ID");
        System.out.println("Value returned:\n"+retVal);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("RemoteException while consuming web service");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Exception while consuming web service");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, main

log4j.appender.main=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.main.MaxFileSize=15MB
log4j.appender.main.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.main.File=logs/DemoRequest.log
log4j.appender.main.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.main.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Comment: First of all i think you have to edit in log4j.properties your variable:

    log4j.appender.main.File=/logs/ISTMRequest.log

Comment: logs are not getting generated even after changing the variable to  log4j.appender.main.File=/logs/ISTMRequest.log

Comment: your path(/logs/) exists? if the folder is not created, it's possible to write in SystemOut.log, so create the folder for logs like your path. long story short: in root, create folder logs :) i am waiting for you answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

From the above code snippets - it seems like its missing the logic to load the log4j.properties file, which you should load in the beginning of your program. So please try adding something like:

```
Properties applicationProp = new Properties();

String applicationPropFilePath = "C:\\log4j.properties";

load( applicationPropFilePath, applicationProp );

/* This method is a cookie-cutter and loads the given properties file to the given handle */
public static void load( String propFilepath, Properties propFileHandle ){
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream( propFilepath );
        propFileHandle.load( is );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(" Unable to locate properties file: " + propFilepath + e ); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(" IO Error while loading properties file: " + propFilepath + e ); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(" Some error occurred while loading properties file: " + propFilepath + e ); 
    }
```